# "in someone's eyes" meaning "in someone's opinion" (AE) and punctuation with phrases of opinion

Tags: semantics, collocation

Is the phrase "in my/his/etc. eyes" as meaning "in my/his/etc. opinion" common in American English? Is it an idiomatic alternative to "in my view" "to my mind" etc.?

> This is, in his eyes, the most severe effect of this development.

As for punctuation with such phrases that express opinion: Is it ok to put them at the end of the sentence and which punctuation would be preferable?

> 1) This is the most severe effect of this development in his eyes.
>
> 2) This is the most severe effect of this development, in his eyes.

Comment: It's usual to offset a pragmatic (here modal ... cautioning that this is the referent's opinion) marker off with a comma where sentence-initial or sentence-terminal.

Comment: Classically, they were/are called sentence adverbials (unless they were less parenthetical, like 'I have heard that ...'). The less reliable-sounding ones have been termed 'hearsay markers'. / One sets off or offsets, but I won't delete the imperfect post.

Answer (score 5):

As you've shown, it's the comma placement that matters:

> A. Sulfuric acid, in my eyes, is useful for unclogging sinks. (okay)
>
> B. Sulfuric acid in my eyes is useful for unclogging sinks. (ouch)

Edit: Placement of the idiom is also helpful for reducing ambiguity:

> A. Pointy sticks, in my eyes, are great for roasting marshmallows. (still problematic)
>
> B. Pointy sticks are great for roasting marshmallows, in my eyes. (better)

Edit edit: I do like it better at the beginning of a sentence, but it doesn't always work:

> A. In my eyes, Sulfuric acid is useful for unclogging sinks. (better)
>
> B. In my eyes, tiny aliens exist. (still ambiguous)

There are instances where it might be better to just use "in my opinion" instead.

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out! But with end position the ambiguity wouldnt be there (and this is I think the case with many examples that would be ambiguous with mid-position): "Sulfuric acid is useful for unclogging sinks in my eyes" Would the comma before "in my eyes" in end position still be the preferred punctuation?

Comment: @SarahK - How do you get the sinks in your eyes to start with?

Comment: Ok I get it! Sorry! It's still ambiguous... In the example I posted above would you therefore also use a comma before the expression "in my eyes" even though there is no immediate ambiguity like in the acid/sink example?

Comment: Like, **in my opinion**, you can also use **from my perspective** instead of "in my eyes**.

Comment: @Hank Is this because "in my eyes" is not idiomatic?

Comment: **in my eyes** is acceptable, but can be confused with something actually being in your eyes. **From my perspective** says the exact same thing without the ambiguity.

Comment: @Cory Why is it that you find "In my eyes, tiny alien exist" (still) ambiguous? Because the literal meaning of the phrase still persists? Thank you very much for your comments!

Comment: I speak American English and I like to say "in my view."  In my view, "in my view" is better.  I don't know how representative my view is, though.

Comment: @SarahK In my opinion "In my eyes, tiny aliens exist" sounds a lot like "Tiny aliens exist in my eyes" (as if they live in my eyeballs). It's the nature of the idiom itself that leads to the ambiguity, in juxtaposition to certain statements. The best uses of "In my eyes" involve a visual/mental opinion, like "My wife of 50 years has grey hair, a stooped back, and wrinkled skin, but in my eyes she's as beautiful as the day we met." That's a use that works for me. Others, like the ones I chose for examples, are less appropriate uses of the idiom to begin with.